# Vuejs and Laravel sending data not working

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.1, vue.js

I have a vue.js script that gets a csv, sends it to my server-side code that breaks it down into an array and sends it back.

Now, I then save that data into a array so the client can edit any data and manipulate ect. Here's the code that dose this:

```
//hide the upload box, and display new message
$('#upload').slideUp();
$('#message').html('Cheers, Just give us a sec to decode the file...');

//get the file and save it into a new File Object ready to send
var files = $('input#csvUpload').prop('files');
var csv_file = new FormData();
csv_file.append('csv_file', files[0]);


//send to a controller that will read this file and return a JSON string!
this.$http.post('uploadCSV', csv_file, function(data){
   //the data is the array returned from the controller,
   //this function is just the call back

   //now for the rows
   this.rows    = data.rows;

   console.log(this.rows);

   //update the message with some new instructions
   $('#message').html("Done, now remove the cards you don't want to process");

   //and show our table
   $('#table').slideDown();

    });
```

[image: this is the data that has been returned]

Now, that all works fine. Nothing wrong with that. the confusing part is that after the end-user has finish making changes, I need to send that data to a controller that will do things with that data. 
But the issue is that when I send the data, laravel can't seem to find it when it gets to the controller.

**The code that sends the data:**

```
  this.$http.post('makePayment', this.rows, function(data){
     this.processed = data;
     console.log(data);
   });
```

[image]

**The Controller Code:**

```
$array = $request->all();
return $array;
exit();
```

[image]

I have a feeling that it is staring at me in the face, but this has really stumped me, and the top picture shows what is in the `this.rows` object.

**Thanks for any help in advance!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, knew it was staring me in the face. So the solution is quite simple. What was happening was that I was sending an array instead of json string...shouldn't matter right? well it does. So the simple solution was before sending the data to my controller, i needed to convert the **array** to **Json** format...

So here's the updated code that sends my data:

```
var newJson = JSON.stringify(this.rows);
this.$http.post('makePayment', newJson, function(data){
      this.processed = data;
      console.log(data);
});
```